# Java heap Xms and linux free memory different

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have a java program running in centos Box.
My -Xmx  and -Xms set to 4000 Mb.

> The program works fine.

But when i do free -m , the used memory is showing as 506 MB. As per my understanding , XMS memory should be reserved for JVM.`Why does free command not showing the java used memory ?`

I have also done jstat -gccapacity $(pidof java) and there  NGCMN  and NGCMX  updated and have the same value ?
Any support would be helpful.
I'm running my program as **java -Xms41000m -Xmx42000m -jar**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even when `-Xmx` and `-Xms` set to the same value, the space reserved for Java Heap is not immediately allocated in RAM.

Operating System typically allocates physical memory lazily, only on the first access to a virtual page. So, while unused part of Java Heap is not touched, it won't really consume memory.

You may use `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` option to forcibly touch all heap pages on JVM start.