# Why does the JVM have more free memory after my test program?

Tags: java, jvm, runtime

I made a test program to test the Runtime.freeMemory() method.

```
public class RuntimeFreeMemory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println(r.freeMemory()); // 246939608

        String[] arr = new String[10000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            arr[i] = new String();

        System.out.println(r.freeMemory()); // 517655928
    }
}
```

Of course, these are big numbers, but I really wanted to test it as numbers like 10000 wouldn't cut it. But when I ran it, I got some unexpected numbers. I thought the end free memory would go down or stay somewhat the same as the initial free memory, but instead they went over *double* what the initial free memory was. I ran this multiple times and it was always something around these values. Can somebody explain this?

Comment: Probably because the JVM asked for more memory from the OS and didn't release it (it usually doesn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `freeMemory` reported may be affected by GC and by the fact that the heap has been expanded because of your array allocations. It might be interesting to also print `r.totalMemory` at the beginning and at the end and compare.

When the JVM starts, it doesn't actually allocate (by default) whole heap memory upfront - it's just "reserved" and later "committed" if/when needed (at that point, heap is expanded).

You can try to set `-Xms` and `-Xmx` explicitly to the same value and will likely get more expected results.

E.g. by using `-Xms8g -Xmx8g` I got following:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println(r.freeMemory()); // 8581851136
        System.out.println(r.totalMemory()); // 8589934592 

        System.out.println("Process PID: " + ProcessHandle.current().pid());

        String[] arr = new String[100000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            arr[i] = new String();

        System.out.println(r.freeMemory()); // 5717141504
        System.out.println(r.totalMemory()); // 8589934592
    }

    // compare results when using ONLY -Xmx8g
    // 537178112
    // 541065216
    // 3240407040
    // 6104809472
```

Note: Using `-Xms` still doesn't (usually) mean that the memory is resident in RAM: [Java heap Xms and linux free memory different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982636/java-heap-xms-and-linux-free-memory-different)

Comment: Thanks, your the best!