JVM heap size is greater than the container's memory limit
I run a Java (21) application in my k8s cluster.
I defined the -Xms and -Xmx values to be 780 mib. If I set a lower value to -Xmx the application crashes with out of memory error.
I set the request and the limit of the container to be 600 mib.
I expected the app to be terminated with an out of memory error, but the container is running.
In addition, by using the kubectl top I see that the container is using 545 mib, and indeed when I set a lower limit the app is crashed with OOM.
How the -Xms and -Xmx are higher than the limit and the container is running?
I see that defining a lower -Xmx value leads to OOM, so I assume the JVM is actually using it, but when I set the limit to this value (lower than -Xmx) the container runs. How is it possible?

You'll get a different symptom if your Java application runs out of Java heap memory (which might be what you're seeing with the lower -Xmx value) vs. if the JVM exceeds the allowable system memory.  With modern JVMs, they can appropriately set the Java memory limits based on the container resource limits, so you shouldn't need -Xms -Xmx options.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48999394/3448419

You have an out of memory error not necessarily because of the heap. It could be because of metaspace area which is growing . -Xms and -Xmx are min and max memory allocation for heap memory area.
In order to solve your problem, you should check and investigate by memory dumps and see why heap memory area fills too quickly using this tag -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
If you are in Kubernetes cluster you could try the following :

Use different garbage collector to optimize your memory.

Allocate higher memory for metaspace area.

Think about autoscaling based memory or cpu metrics.


